# Отступ элемента с абсолютным позиционированием относительно фона

Tags: css, html

К блоку с шириной 100% (нужно именно 100%) вешаем background картинку дома (с позиционированием cover) и нужно внутри создать блок в котором будет ссылка и поставить его на окно этого дома. Соответственно отступ слева на всех мониторах будет разный и задать фиксированную величину не вариант, что делать?

P.S. нужно создать интерактивный дом, где при наведение на стену/окно/лестницу/дверь и прочее рядом будет выскакивать подсказка. Flash не катит.

Comment: image map не годится? вместо фона img с area

Comment: Но не совсем подошло, ибо требует денег за возможность масштабирования...

Comment: Не понятно как это может требовать денег

Comment: Там во вкладке Zoom, для масштабирования ссылок просят подписку оформить за 5 баксов

Comment: Это ещё что за хрень такая - масштабирование ссылок? html - Это же просто текстовый файл, что там масштабировать?

Comment: Прошу прощения затупил, я по запарке думал, что речь идет не о самой карте, а о генераторе карт. Нашел решение в подключении js image map resizer. Еще раз извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для абсолютного позиционирования внутри блока, нужно задать `position: relative` родителю и `position: absolute` чилду.

`background-position: center;` обеспечит центрирование изображения, что позволит на разных разрешениях экрана от середины позиционировать ссылки

HTML

```
<div class='background'>
    <div class='link'><a href='#'>link</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('/img/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}

.link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Я бы не стал делать `cover` для изображения, на котором точно в конкретном месте должна быть ссылка. Проще сделать блок с изображением и задать ему `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Не совсем понял второй вариант, ведь если просто сделать блок с overflow: hidden мы получим удобный вариант для absolute позиционирования ссылок, но потеряем адаптивность, ибо на телефоне отрежет часть картинки, на fullhd наоборот картинки не хватит.

Comment: вариант выше не подошел, ссылку если тыкнуть то она не сильно меняет позицию при масштабировании, что в принципе приемлимо, а вот если объект побольше (например картинку с ссылкой), то ее начинает кидать в стороны при масштабировании.

Comment: @f1amestar, предоставь код чтоли с картинкой, добавь в свой вопрос как должно быть

Comment: Уже решил проблему, отказался от cover да и от блока с шириной 100%. Сделал фиксированную ширину в px и забил. А так ради интереса перепробовал много чего и подошел только вариант с написание image map. Если интересно решение нашел в этом: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer